# ELMAH MVC 2 - Issue with Castle Windsor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

I've just installed ELMAH MVC (v2) into my web application but when I try to view the logs at /elmah I get the following exception

**No component for supporting the service Elmah.Mvc.ElmahController was found**
[ComponentNotFoundException: No component for supporting the service Elmah.Mvc.ElmahController was found]
   Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve(Type service) +140
   Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Resolve(Type service) +40
   N2.Engine.Castle.WindsorServiceContainer.Resolve(Type type) +40
   N2.Engine.ContentEngine.Resolve(Type serviceType) +48

The web site includes the N2 CMS system which in turn uses Castle Windsor.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out the solution shortly after posting the question. I needed to register the Elmah controller with N2:

```
var engine = MvcEngine.Create();
engine.RegisterControllers(typeof(GlobalApplication).Assembly);
engine.RegisterControllers(typeof(ElmahController).Assembly);
```

Answer (score 15):

I know this already has an accepted answer, and it's not entirely relevant to your question, but for anyone else **not** using N2 and running into issues with Elmah.MVC+Castle Windsor, you need to register the controllers in the **Elmah.MVC** assembly with Windsor. I made a simple installer to handle this for me:

```
public class ElamhInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Elmah.Mvc")
            .BasedOn<IController>()
            .LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

Once I added this Castle seems to be able to find the `ElmahController` just fine.

Comment: Thanks. The only thing I had to change to make my integration tests work in Team City was "Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Elmah.Mvc")" to this "Classes.FromAssembly(typeof(ElmahController).Assembly)". Some kind of optimization removed the dll and I got "Could not load file or assembly 'Elmah.Mvc'"

Answer (score 0):

ELMAH.MVC comes App_Start code, that uses Web.Activator to register ElmahController route.

So, it's strange for me, why Windor fails to load ElmahController. By default, it should try to resolve it by itself, then if not possible delegate to ControllerFactory.

Are you sure, application got restarted (iisreset.exe) after ELMAH installed?

Comment: Hi Alexander, I just retested to ensure that I had restarted IIS (IIS Express in this case as its on a dev machine) I and definitely have to register the Elmah controller with the N2 engine to be able to view the Elmah logs

Comment: @alexanderb Hey Alex, I'm using Windsor too with Elmah.MVC (first time with this flavour) and when I go to mysite.com/elmah i get the message "No component for supporting the service Elmah.Mvc.ElmahController was found".  Any hints?  Also, I couldn't find any dedicated documentation on Elmah.MVC apart from bits and pieces in your blog.

Comment: @DanB hi Dan, unfortunatelly it's to difficult to diagnose the problem just from "air" :).. I would like to ask you for a favor - could you please raise up issue on [github](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah.mvc) and sent "broken" solution to mine e-mail address (in my profile). I promise to find the problem and got back with solution :)

Comment: @alexanderb, I saw that there was a issue with SSL using Elmah.MVC and that's a deal breaker for me - so no longer persuing the issue.  Instead I am writing my own provider so that I can just use code first instead (I like pain lol) - yeah there are some wonderful startup things in Elmah.MVC but the path to success not as fluid as I would have hoped for my particular setup with.  I'm not doing anything particularly fancy with CastleWindsor so it should be fairly easy to try out.  Might revisit after some time - but ease of use of code first was my main reason for not using it. Thanks! Dan.